# select by attribute and calculate field: fiona, geopandas

Tags: python, fiona, geopandas, pandas

This may be more of a python question than gis, but I have 3 bands in a polygon layer, and I would like to select earthquakes within each band and calculate a new field to note these locations (band 1,2,3). I created a filter to select the band, and want to spatial join this with earthquakes. We do not want to use processing module, as my coworkers are unfamilar with qgis or arcgis. Here is the code so far:

```
with fiona.open("filepath/bands.shp") as src:
    filtered = filter(lambda f: f['band_1']['band_numbe']=='bar', src)
```

and (skipping steps of transforming to geodataframe with geopandas), from here I would like to use sjoin:

```
pointInPolys = gpd.tools.sjoin(geo_eq,src, how='inner', op = 'within').
```

Any ideas of how to do this using a filter? or a better way to obtain a subset for each band?